# Sum numbers right, no matter the format

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this function that sum's regex results:

```js
'use strict';

function sum(string) {
    var match, result, pattern;

    pattern = /[\d,\.]+/g
    match = string.match(pattern);
 
    if (!match.length) {
      return 'Didn\'t find any trace.';
    }

    result = match.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      curr = curr.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
      return prev + (+curr);
    }, 0);

    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return 'The sum fails.';
    }
}

console.log(sum('156,02 10')); // expected: 166.02 = works
console.log(sum('10.10 10.10')); // expected: 20.20 = doesn't work, result = 2020
console.log(sum('01.10 2,30')); // expected: 3.40 = doesn't work, result = 112.3
```

And is working only when i have the format 152,02. I would like it to accept all formats. Is it possible? There isn't any lib to help?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would `2,30` be converted to `2.30` ?

Comment: @guest271314 It's a locale issue "thing". In some countries 2,30 is actually 2.30. Digits being separated by comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  removing `.replace(/\./g, '')` , including `+` operator before `prev` to cast as `prev` string to `Number`

```js
'use strict';

function sum(string) {
    var match, result, pattern;

    pattern = /(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+,\d+)|(\d+)/g;
    match = string.match(pattern);
 
    if (!match.length) {
      return 'Didn\'t find any trace.';
    }

    result = match.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      curr = curr.replace(',', '.');
      return +prev + (+curr);
    }, 0);

    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return 'The sum fails.';
    }
}

console.log(sum('156,02 10')); // expected: 166.02 = works
console.log(sum('10.10 10.10')); // expected: 20.20 = doesn't work, result = 2020
console.log(sum('01.10 2,30')); // expected: 3.40 = doesn't work, result = 112.3
```